# how to select light DOM in angular component

Tags: dart, components, angular-dart

I try to select everything inside the content tag in an angular component

```dart
<my-component>
  <another-component></another-component>
  <another-component></another-component>
  <another-component></another-component>
</my-component>
```

my-component.html

```dart
<div>
  <content></content>
</div>
```

my-component.dart

```dart
@Component(
  selector: "my-component",
  templateUrl: 'components/my-component.html',
  useShadowDom: false,
  publishAs: "ctrl"
)
class MyComponent {
   List<Element> content; //elements of content tags
}
```

How can i select everything inside of  and put it into my list. 
Is there a special method where i can access the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a constructor to `MyComponent` with an argument of type `Element` and select the children.

```dart
class MyComponent {
  List<Element> content; //elements of content tags

  MyComponent(Element e) {
    content = <Element>[].addAll(e.children);
    // or
    content = <Element>[].addAll((e.querySelector('content') as ContentElement).getDistributedNodes());
  }
}
```

(use with caution, didn't test the code and didn't use Angular.dart for a while)

Comment: works perfect. i reduced the constructor body to: content.addAll(e.children);